# How to find a XML tag with a specific attribute (in C#)

Tags: c#, xml, dita

I need to get a list of tags that contain a specific attribute. I am using DITA xml and I need to find out all tags that has a href attribute.

The problem here is that the attribute may be inside any tag so XPath will not work in this case. For example, an image tag may contain a href, a topicref tag may contain a href, and so on.

So I need to get a `XmlNodeList` (as returned by the `getElementByTagName` method). Ideally I need a method `getElementByAttributeName` that should return `XmlNodeList`.

Comment: XPATH is *totally* an option.  You can use `*` as a wildcard match for any element, as @Chris Taylor's answer demonstrates.

Comment: Thanks Mads. I did not know that we can use wildcards in XPATH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might have misunderstood your problem here, but I think you could possibly use an XPath expression.

```
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//*[@href='pic1.jpg']");
```

The above should return all elements with `href='pic1.jpg'`, where `doc` is the `XmlDocument`

Comment: The more generic XPATH to return all elements that have an href attribute, regardless of what it's value is: `//*[@href]`

Answer (score 3):

If you're on C#, then the following approach might work for you:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
XAttribute xa = new XAttribute("href", "pic1.jpg");
var attrList = document.Descendants().Where (d => d.Attributes().Contains(xa));
```